# Getting CSS width of dynamically created element (Javascript, DOM)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm experimenting with adding `divs` to the DOM programmatically.  I want to arrange them in a circle within a "master" `div`,

```
<body>
<div id="master">


</div>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

thusly:

```
window.addEventListener('load',init);

let master;

function init() {
    master = document.getElementById('master');

    const count = 8;
    const radius = 50;
    for (let i=0; i<count;i++){
        const diva = document.createElement('div');
        diva.id = i;
        master.appendChild(diva);
        let {x,y} = returnCoords(100,100,degreesToRad((360/count) * i),radius);
        diva.style.left = x + "px";
        diva.style.top = y + "px";
        console.log(diva.style.width); // empty!
    }

}

function degreesToRad(degrees) {
   return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);

}

function radToDegrees(rad) {
    return radians * (180 / Math.PI);

}

function returnCoords(originX = 0, originY = 0,radians,radius) {
    let x = originX + (Math.cos(radians) * radius);
    let y = originY + (Math.sin(radians) * radius);
    return ({x,y});
}
```

These `div`s are styled by SCSS:

```
#master {
  background:pink;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  position: relative;
  div {
    background: white;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    border:blueviolet solid 1px;
    position:absolute;
  }
}
```

And this all works fine.  However I can't get the `width` of the `div`, even after it's added into the DOM. The line `console.log(diva.style.width);` produces nothing.  Thus I can't move the `divs` based on their width.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.style` property reads the *inline* styles of an element, not the ones assigned by CSS.  Confusing, for sure.  Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style